# Simultaneous image capture on multiple webcams at supported image resolution

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

We are trying to capture images from multiple external webcams at a resolution that each webcam best supports through a cocoa application. We are not able to capture all feeds dot at the same time i.e. simultaneous capture on all webcams as we are unable to open all webcams simultaneously and call capture method.

We have managed to take images at supported resolution from each webcam but only with a delay of 3 seconds between 2 images becoz we are triggering capture process for each webcam separately.

We have got 2 very specific requirements for this app…

1. Images captured should be of the highest resolution a webcam supports.
2. There should be absolutely no time delay in images captured from various feeds.

Source code for capturing images at supported resolution but with 3 sec time delay…

```
-(void)initailzeCamera{
    if( [cameraArray count] == 0 ) {
                exit( 1 );
    }
    if(cameraCount >= [cameraArray count]){
        cameraCount = 0;
    }
    if(videoDevice){
        //[mCaptureSession stopRunning];

    }
    videoDevice = [cameraArray objectAtIndex:cameraCount];
    if(![videoDevice isOpen])
        [videoDevice open:nil];

    if( !videoDevice ) {
        exit( 1 );
    }
    if(mCaptureDeviceInput){
        [mCaptureDeviceInput release];
    }
    mCaptureDeviceInput = [[QTCaptureDeviceInput alloc] initWithDevice:videoDevice];
    mCaptureSession = [[QTCaptureSession alloc] init];
    [mCaptureSession addInput:mCaptureDeviceInput error:nil];   
    [mCaptureSession startRunning];
    [mCaptureView setCaptureSession:mCaptureSession];
    [mCaptureView setVideoPreviewConnection:[[mCaptureView availableVideoPreviewConnections] objectAtIndex:0]];
    [mCaptureView setHidden:YES];
    [mCaptureSession startRunning];

    [self performSelector:@selector(stopCamera) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0]; 

}

// This delegate method is called whenever the QTCaptureDecompressedVideoOutput receives a frame
- (CIImage *)view:(QTCaptureView *)view willDisplayImage:(CIImage *)image{

    NSBitmapImageRep *bitmapRep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithCIImage:image];
    jpegData =[[bitmapRep representationUsingType:NSJPEGFileType properties:nil]retain];

    return image;

}
-(void)stopCamera{
    @try {
        [mCaptureSession stopRunning];
        NSString *path= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[locationLabel stringValue]];

      NSString *imagePath=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",path] retain];
        NSString *imageName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg",[[[NSDate date]description] substringToIndex:19]];
        imageName = [imageName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@"."];
        NSString *appFile = [imagePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];


        if(jpegData != nil){
            if([jpegData writeToFile:[appFile stringByExpandingTildeInPath] atomically:YES]){
                    }else {
            }
        }
        else {
                NSException*  jpegDataNullException= [NSException exceptionWithName:@"JpegDataNullException"
                                                  reason:@"jpegData null found"
                                                  userInfo:nil];
            @throw jpegDataNullException;
        }


        cameraCount++;

        if(!flagForPause){ 
            if(cameraCount < [cameraArray count]){
                [self performSelector:@selector(initailzeCamera) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
            }else{
                if(flagForAutoMode){
                    [self performSelector:@selector(initailzeCamera) withObject:nil afterDelay:[timeREcquire intValue]-5];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException * e) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Capturing multiple cameras works just fine using `QTKit`. You simply open two sessions and let them run in parallel (you may even open one session and add two input sources if you don't need to control them separately). Starting a device capture takes seconds, that's one reason why the above doesn't work well - you have to keep both sessions running. The other problem is that you are using preview for capturing which can result in quality degradation. If you want full resolution capture, you should be using `captureOutput:didOutputVideoFrame:withSampleBuffer:fromConnection:` which delivers full-size frames.

An example of how it could be done is in http://svn.rforge.net/osx/trunk/tools/wcam.m

That code is intended for slow capture (1 fps), so for your use you may remove or modify `[dvo setMinimumVideoFrameInterval:1.0];` to suit your needs (but note that storing the image must still be fast enough not to choke the capture).

Answer (score 1):

Tried to use the source code provided by you but the issue i am having is that one webcam takes only one picture and stops and the 2nd webcam keeps taking pictures.

```
devices = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[QTCaptureDevice inputDevicesWithMediaType:QTMediaTypeVideo]] retain];
    //[devices removeObject:[QTCaptureDevice defaultInputDeviceWithMediaType:QTMediaTypeVideo]];
    
    int devId = 0;
    for (QTCaptureDevice *device in devices) {
        NSLog(@"device: %@", device);
        Capture *cap = [[Capture alloc] initWithDevice: device];
        [cap setFileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image.%d.%%04d.jpeg", ++devId]];
        [cap start];
    }
    if ([devices count] == 0) {
        NSLog(@"no devices found, terminating");
        exit (1);
    }
```